# html form input and select not working on touch devices

Tags: jquery, html, touch

I'm trying to build a site that will work on the desktop and with tablets. Obviously touch devices pose some challenges such as button clicks. I've got past that but now the button I click opens up a form. This form contains some select and input types.

Click this button:

```
<button class="addwebcam">Add Webcam</button>
```

and this opens up a form:

```
<div id="cameraformwebcam" title="Add a webcam">
    <form id='AddCameraFormWebcam' action=''>
        <p>
        <label for="CameraName">Camera name:
        <span class="small">Enter label for camera</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" id="CameraName" name="camera_name" size="24" maxlength="36" />
        </p>
        <p>
        <label for='CameraQuality'>Camera quality:
        <span class="small">Select camera quality</span>
        </label>
        <select id='CameraQuality' name='camera_quality'>
            <option value='HIGH' selected='selected'>High</option>
            <option value='MEDIUM'>Medium</option>
            <option value='MOBILE'>Mobile</option>
        </select>
        </p>
        <p>
        <label for='CameraStatus'>Motion detection:
        <span class="small">Turn motion detection on/off</span>
        </label>
        <select id='CameraStatus' name='camera_status'>
            <option value='ENABLED' selected='selected'>On</option>
            <option value='DISABLED'>Off</option>
        </select>
        </p>
        <p>
        <label for='EmailNotice'>Email notice:
        <span class="small">Turn email notices on/off</span>
        </label>
        <select id='EmailNotice' name='email_notice'>
            <option value='ENABLED' selected='selected'>On</option>
            <option value='DISABLED'>Off</option>
        </select>
        </p>
        <p>
        <label for='CameraSensitivity'>Camera sensitivity:
        <span class="small">Select camera sensitivity</span>
        </label>
        <select id='CameraSensitivity' name='camera_sensitivity'>
            <option value='HIGH'>High</option>
            <option value='AVERAGE' selected='selected'>Average</option>
            <option value='LOW'>Low</option>
        </select>
        </p>
        <input type='hidden' name='camera_type' value='WEBCAM' />
        <button type='submit' class='submit_camera' name='addcamera' value='Add'>Add</button>
        <button type='reset' class='cancel_changes' name='cancel_changes' value='Cancel'>Cancel</button>
    </form>
    </div>
```

My problem is that the form doesn't work when tested on tablets (just fine on desktops). The select types just highlight but do not open to show the selections and the input type for the camera name also just highlights but the keyboard doesn't open.

This is handled with jquery:

```
jQuery(".addwebcam").live('touchstart click', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    touchStart(event);
    if(event.handled !== true) {

        jQuery('#cameraformwebcam').show();
    jQuery('.addwebcam').hide();

        event.handled = true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

You will notice the `touchStart` function. This was a question I found **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251150/ipad-ios-html-form-select-does-not-open-on-touch)** to get select to work on touch devices. That doesn't work plus I need all fields to work including the input type.

```
function touchStart(event) {
   if (event.target.tagName != 'SELECT') {
      event.preventDefault();
   }
}
```

My goal here is to keep one site that works for both tablets and desktop sites (mobile devices are different). Especially since it only has a couple of buttons and forms. So I'm trying to avoid using jquery mobile and creating a separate page for tablets.

Comment: I'm not sure you should have `event.stopPropagation();` there - see the first note on the relevant jQuery documentation (http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) - "Since the `.live()` method handles events once they have propagated to the top of the document, it is not possible to stop propagation of live events." - I suspect this might be stopping your form from working correctly?

Comment: @Coder I did try to remove but no changes. Thanks for looking.

Comment: You're not using iscroll are you?

Comment: Does it work if you disable the scripts and just run the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

I have create a fiddle with your piece of code and have made some small changes and tested it on iphone / ipad & desktop, work fine for me: 
 here html:

```
<button id="addwebcam">Add Webcam</button>
<div id="cameraformwebcam" title="Add a webcam">
    <form id='AddCameraFormWebcam' action=''>
        <p>
            <label for="CameraName">Camera name: <span class="small">Enter label for camera</span>

            </label>
            <input type="text" id="CameraName" name="camera_name" size="24" maxlength="36" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for='CameraQuality'>Camera quality: <span class="small">Select camera quality</span>

            </label>
            <select id='CameraQuality' name='camera_quality'>
                <option value='HIGH' selected='selected'>High</option>
                <option value='MEDIUM'>Medium</option>
                <option value='MOBILE'>Mobile</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for='CameraStatus'>Motion detection: <span class="small">Turn motion detection on/off</span>

            </label>
            <select id='CameraStatus' name='camera_status'>
                <option value='ENABLED' selected='selected'>On</option>
                <option value='DISABLED'>Off</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for='EmailNotice'>Email notice: <span class="small">Turn email notices on/off</span>

            </label>
            <select id='EmailNotice' name='email_notice'>
                <option value='ENABLED' selected='selected'>On</option>
                <option value='DISABLED'>Off</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for='CameraSensitivity'>Camera sensitivity: <span class="small">Select camera sensitivity</span>

            </label>
            <select id='CameraSensitivity' name='camera_sensitivity'>
                <option value='HIGH'>High</option>
                <option value='AVERAGE' selected='selected'>Average</option>
                <option value='LOW'>Low</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <input type='hidden' name='camera_type' value='WEBCAM' />
        <button type='submit' class='submit_camera' name='addcamera' value='Add'>Add</button>
        <button type='reset' class='cancel_changes' name='cancel_changes' value='Cancel'>Cancel</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

here js:

```
$('#cameraformwebcam').hide();
$("#addwebcam").click(function(event){

    event.stopPropagation();
    touchStart(event);
    if(event.handled !== true) {

        $('#cameraformwebcam').show();
    $('.addwebcam').hide();

        event.handled = true;

    } else {
        return false;
    }
});

function touchStart(event) {
   if (event.target.tagName != 'SELECT') {
      event.preventDefault();
       alert(event);
   }
}
$('.submit_camera').click(function(){
    alert("Send data");


});
```

[Link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/konstheinrich188/TKfEJ/)

hope it helps

Comment: Would be helpful to know what the differences are without having to find it out manually by comparing the code line by line. Furthermore, it's piece of code, not peace.